# How to get Chatter Only (Chatter Plus) licenses for my org?

Tags: chatter, approval-process, enterprise, winter19

I have looked over the [help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_chatter.htm&type=5) page but there was no guide whatsoever on how to obtain Chatter Only (Chatter Plus) [Basically Chatter with most features] licenses.

I have even explored my production **Enterprise** Edition org to try find the part where I might need to buy more licenses as below :

> Company Information > Buy more Licenses > Order Tab > Show all available products > No Chatter plus?

[image: Salesforce licenses]

Advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm assuming that you do have the features enabled needed to use those licenses. If you do not, that may be the reason they are not showing as available for you to purchase for your org. [From the docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_chatter.htm&type=5):

> The Chatter Only license is available for purchase only by existing Chatter Plus customers. For new customers, the Lightning Platform Starter license is a step up from Chatter Only, giving your users access to a more robust set of features.

If you do not currently use Chatter Plus licenses and Lightning Platform Starter Licenses do not show as available to you, then you will want to contact your Account Executive (AE) to purchase licenses that are not available via the link inside your org that you've referenced. Your AE should be listed in your Company Information Page. Otherwise you can Contact Salesforce and they will have your AE contact you.

Comment: That statement is absolute cancer - "available for purchase only by existing Chatter Plus customers". It's like saying I can only buy Tesla cars if I have an existing Tesla car - how do you even get that in the first place? 
Yeah luckily I am an admin in that prod site .. so that is how I am able to see that page. So I have to call salesforce?

Comment: @compski Please do not shoot the messenger. Salesforce does this when it is phasing out a license as do other companies.

Comment: not shooting you - sorry if it seemed that way. Just saying that when I read that line on their help page - I was like ok that's nice to know but doesn't answer my root question of where to get/buy it.

Comment: @compski No biggie. The Help page does answer your question by telling you that you cannot purchase those licenses if you do not already use them. I know that isn't what you want to hear. Community etiquette is to help others by marking your question as solved through checking the box on an answer that resolves your issue. (even if you're not happy about it) If you don't, it leaves the impression to anyone who searches the topic later that your question wasn't answered to your satisfaction. Once you have sufficient reputation, you can also upvote posts and answers.